# Unpacking "stored" variadic template types into template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write mocks for use in unit tests. To do this, I need to mirror the real implementation of a library I can not change. Here is a very simplified example:

LibraryCodeICantChange.h:

```
struct IFoo {};
struct IBar {};

template<typename... I>
struct implements {};

template<typename... I>
struct mocks {};

struct CRealSingle : implements<IFoo> {};
struct CRealMulti : implements<IFoo, IBar> {};
```

Simply, my mocks are like so:

```
#include "LibraryCodeICantChange.h"

struct CMockSingle : mocks<IFoo> {};
struct CMockMulti : mocks<IFoo, IBar> {};
```

However, I would like to infer the interface list from the real, rather than duplicate it. I got it work for a single interface, but I need a variadic set of templates parameters of the interfaces. I stored the variadic types into a struct I called `pack` but I don't know how to unpack those types:

```
#include "LibraryCodeICantChange.h"

template<typename... I>
struct pack {};

// just declared, not defined: only used for typing
template<typename... I>
pack<I...> steal_real_params(implements<I...>*);

template<typename C>
using steal_real_params_t = decltype(steal_real_params(std::declval<C*>()));

template<typename C>
struct MockBasedOnReal: mocks<steal_real_params_t<C>... /* how to unpack? */> {};
// error C3546: '...': there are no parameter packs available to expand

struct CMockSingle : MockBasedOnReal<CRealSingle> {}; // error while 'MockBasedOnReal<CRealSingle>' being compiled
struct CMockMulti : MockBasedOnReal<CRealMulti> {}; // error while 'MockBasedOnReal<CMockMulti>' being compiled
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how?

Comment: You must edit your question so that the parts that you've supposedly implemented meet all the requirements of a [mcve]. As such, the first code sample completely fails to compile due to bad declarations (`impl` not defined, etc...) Although I think I can see what you're trying to accomplish, since "what you've come up with so far" is nowhere near compilable, as is, it would take too much time to figure out what needs to be fixed in order to make it compile, which is a necessary prerequisite to figuring out what is the missing piece.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've cut a lot out of the question/code to make it more minimal and verifiable. You should be able to copy the top and bottom code block and experience the same problem I'm having. I hope it's more understandable now too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I understand your question, it boils down to this starting point:

```
struct CRealMulti : implements<IFoo, IBar> {};
```

And you'd like to have a template that you can feed this `CRealMulti` class into, and then be able to derive something that inherits from `mocks<Ifoo, IBar>`. Tested with gcc 7.1.1:

```
#include <utility>

struct IFoo {};
struct IBar {};
struct IBaz {};

template<typename... I>
struct implements {};

template<typename... I>
struct mocks {};

struct CRealSingle : implements<IFoo> {};
struct CRealMulti : implements<IFoo, IBar> {};

// Given a subclass of implements<I...>, extract it:

template<typename ...I>
implements<I...> return_implements(implements<I...> &&);

// Specialization to extract the parameter pack:

template<typename T> struct implements_to_mocks;

template<typename ...I>
struct implements_to_mocks<implements<I...>> {

    typedef mocks<I...> mocks_t;
};

// All the hard work is here:

template<typename C> struct to_mock {

    typedef decltype(return_implements(std::declval<C &&>())) implements_t;

    typedef typename implements_to_mocks<implements_t>::mocks_t type;
};

// to_mock_t provides a convenient shortcut

template<typename T>
using to_mock_t=typename to_mock<T>::type;

// The end result:
//    
// to_mock_t<CRealMulti> is an alias for mocks<IFoo, IBar>, ready
// and waiting to be inherited from.

void foo()
{
    typedef std::enable_if<std::is_same<
        to_mock_t<CRealMulti>, mocks<IFoo, IBar>>::value>::type t;
}
```